# [Python]Encoding and execfile

Tags: python, windows, unicode, encoding, execfile

I am trying to do something like that using python 2.4:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

afile = unicode('C:\\國立國語院.py', 'UTF-8')
execfile(afile.encode("UTF-8",'replace'))
```

And I receive this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9c\x8b\xe7\xab\x8b\xe5\x9c\x8b\xe8\xaa\x9e\xe9\x99\xa2.py'
```

So my question is how can I do an execfile if the file I want to exec have a name with Korean chars?

Thank you very much

Comment: What name do you see for that file in `os.listdir("C:\\")` and `os.listdir(u"C:\\")`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just be able to do `execfile(afile)` with a unicode argument on Windows, but I can't test it.

If not, get the file system encoding:

```
import sys
fsenc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
execfile(afile.encode(fsenc))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

I do it like that

#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os


afile =  u'C:\\國立國語院.py'
fsenc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
execfile(afile.encode(fsenc))


And i still have No such file or directory: 'C:\\?????.py

Comment: But what happens if you just give the unicode filename to `execfile` *without* encoding it first? You shouldn't need to encode the filename explicitly at all (although the specific Python version may affect that - this is an area where Python has improved in recent versions).

Comment: If I just give the unicode filename I have this error : 

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 3-7`

Comment: #Kvoste I have test this answer on my PC ( win7 Chinese version ), and it runs without any problem. PS: My getfilesystemencoding() is "mbcs".

Comment: @Kvoste: OK, maybe execfile can't handle that unicode. Try @J.F. Sebastian's answer: open it, read it, and `exec` it. For some background, see this PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0277/

Comment: For me it's not working at all...
Can it be a Windows XP problem and not a python one?

Comment: PEP 277 allows most file-handling interfaces to accept a Unicode string for access to Windows filenames outside the limitations of filesystemencoding. However `execfile` was not granted this feature, possibly because it was viewed as deprecated; it has been removed from Python since, with `exec open(...).read()` as the generally-foreseen replacement.

Answer (score 2):

[@Thomas K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855550/pythonencoding-and-execfile/5855919#5855919) should work (it works on Linux and doesn't work in Wine on Python2.4).

[`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) could be emulated using [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

exec open(ur'C:\國立國語院.py').read()
```

Comment: I have the same problem as I have with exevfile :(

Comment: Exact example/error? This works for me, as long as the actual string is definitely right, eg. `exec open(u'C:\\\u570b\u7acb\u570b\u8a9e\u9662.py')` to isolate source encoding problems. Obviously if the target `.py` file itself contains non-ASCII characters, it too will need the `coding` header comment.